# vertical scroll is changeing an percentage width

Tags: css, html

I have a percentage width on a table and an overflow-y:auto. When scroll appears, the width of the table is shirked. 
How can i make the table have the same width (with or without the scroll)
Thank you!

Here is my css:

```
    html,body{height:99%;}
.table1
 { margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  width:98.1%; 
  height:5%; 
  text-align: box-sizing: border-box; 
  left;table-layout: fixed; 
 }
.table1 td
 { border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding-left: 3px;
 }
#container
 { overflow-y:auto; 
  height:20%; 
  width:100%;left:0;  
  right:0;
 }

.table2
 { margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  left:0; 
  right:0; 
  min-width:98.1%; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  table-layout: fixed;
 }
 .table2 tr 
  { height:30px;
  }
.table2 td 
 { margin: 0; 
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey; 
  border-top:none; 
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
 }
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body  BGCOLOR="#EAEAEA" TOPMARGIN=0 LEFTMARGIN=0 RIGHTMARGIN=0 >
  <table class ="table1">
    <colgroup>
      <col width="20%"/>
      <col width="50%"/>
      <col width="30%"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div id="container">
  <table class="table2" BGCOLOR="WHITE">
    <colgroup>
      <col width="20%"/>
      <col width="50%"/>
      <col width="30%"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr>               
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>               
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>               
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>               
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>               
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
html,body{height:99%;}
.table1
 { margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  width:calc(100% - 17px);
  height:5%; 
  text-align:left; 
 }
.table1 td
 { border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding-left: 3px;
 }
#container
 { overflow-y:scroll;
  height:20%; 
  width:100%;left:0;  
  right:0;
 }

.table2
 { margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  left:0; 
  right:0; 
  width:100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  table-layout: fixed;

 }
 .table2 tr 
  { height:30px;
  }
.table2 td 
 { 

  border: 1px solid lightgrey; 
  border-top:none; 
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
 }
```

You can see changes in `container` where I used `width:calc(100% - 17px);`. `Width` of `container` is decreased for `17px` (width of *scroller*) but I, also, change this `overflow-y:scroll;`. Now all lines will be, well, in line :)

You don't need `border-collapse` in `.table1 td` and `.table2 td`... and `overflow` too.

Point is in that `width:calc(100% - XYpx)`, in this case `17px` (width of *scrollbar*)

I hope this is what You need.

There is [Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hesf7v57/)

**Update:**

I create two `js` functions. First one check is there *scrollbar* in `container` element and adapt `width` of him. Second function is just for test, simulating if, in this case, `height` is changed.

In reality, when You add more rows, which count is more then `container` `height`, Your table will adapt. Or on resize browser, too.

In Your case You don't need that second `js` function called `chVl()`, it's in fiddle just for test, like I said before.

[Try this Fiddle now](https://jsfiddle.net/6exkz4gm/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much nelek! This works great! But isn`t there a way without showing the scroller all the time?

Comment: @elas No problem. I use all the time this way. Well, You can, but then You have to use `js`, `hidden field` because every `postback` etc. `js` will calculate difference of `container` element `offsetWidth` and `clientWidth`, then put result in some `hiddenfield` (because `postback`), and change `width` of `container`, all the time. Or maybe someone can better explain this with some example. I don't mind if scrollebar is visible, but that is my opinion.

Comment: @elas btw. in js function I put one code `document.getElementById('tbl1').style.width='calc(100% - 17px)';` ... instead this use little modified one : `var w=pp.offsetWidth-pp.clientWidth; document.getElementById('tbl1').style.width='calc(100% - '+w.toString()+'px)';` ... then *decreased* width will be equal to browser *scrollbar* width. It's much more accurate. You can see now in updated fiddle, again ;)

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot nelek!

Answer (score 0):

remove `overflow-y:auto;` in `#container`

like so:

```
#container
{ 
  height:20%; 
  width:100%;
  left:0;  
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: I removed overflow-y:auto in #container and now it does not show the scroll any more. I want the scroll to show when needed. But i don`t want the width of table2 to shrink when scroll shows. You can delete a tr from table2 and see the difference.

Comment: @Christopher Bednar If `overflow` is removed, scroller will not show and rest of table will not be accessible. I provide solution with some little changes, but that mean *scroller* will be visible all time.

Comment: Ahh okay, my mistake. I misinterpreted what was meant by "with or without the scroll" and didn't quite realize that elements were missing. Next time I'll make sure to pay attention to details like that.

Comment: It's happen to me, too.. sometimes often :( ... :)